# initializationError when trying to use JUnit in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit, junit4

I am trying to do Java unit testing in Visual studio code using JUnit.
I have:

- Installed JUnit 4 jar to a folder
- Made a reference to the .jar in VSCodes "Referenced Libraries" section
- Made simple folder structure using no build tools

This is the directory structure of the project

```
(root project)
   |__ src/com/example
        |__ Add.java
   |__ src/test
        |__ TestAdd.java
```

Add.java:

```
package src.com.example;

public class Add {
    public Add() {
    }
    
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

TestAdd.java:

```
package src.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import src.com.example.Add;

public class TestAdd {

    public TestAdd() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        Add add = new Add();
        
        assertEquals(2, add.add(1, 1));
    }
}
```

**The issue**

When I click run test, VSCode doesn't run the tests and says:

> initializationError(src.test.TestAdd)

As the reason for not running the test under the testing tab in VSCode.

**Screenshots:**
Folder structure + libraries:
[Folder structure + libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw7Aq.png)
Error shown:
[Error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHzAq.png)

**Please be forgiving, this is my first StackOverflow question - apologies in advance!**

Comment: I can't see an error in the screenshot you shared, other than a red indicator. Can you highlight the error? I feel as though I'm missing somthing.

Comment: You need to configure your build path. Java Build Path > Libraries tab click on 'Add Library' button select JUnit click Next. Or else create any simple Maven project it includes JUnit library by default.

Comment: @AkSh I have done this in VSCode, using the Referenced Libraries method and I check the settings.json file and the jar file is there under "java.project.referencedLibraries". 
I am following this exact flow: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/blob/main/release-notes/v0.9.0.md#work-with-jar-files-directly

Comment: @Mureinik In the screenshot in the "Error shown". image, on the left it says 0/1 test passed and shows:
initializationError(src.test.TestAdd)
This is the error. I cannot run the tests?

Comment: Have you tried removing the constructor from `TestAdd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to introduce the JUnit4 dependencies without the build tools. You need to download 2 jars, and add both of them to the referenced libraries in VS Code. Check: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install#plain-old-jar

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it. Didn't have the hamcrest-core jar file in my lib folder or in Referenced libraries in VSCode

Answer (score 0):

The import statement should be

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```